# Allow viewer to embed OpenLayers in their own site?

Tags: openlayers-2

I am trying to create a way for someone viewing my site to embed the map they are viewing into their own site. Not sure where to begin on this.

Any help?

Comment: <iframe>? http://www.iframehtml.com/

Comment: Do you already use OpenLayers on your own site?  If so, you would typically provide some of the code that you are already using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Street Map has a simple tutorial on adding an OpenLayers viewer to your website.  If you are using your own data, just change the layer sources.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OpenLayers_Simple_Example

Alternatively, Leaflet's Quick Start Guide also show you how to make an Open Street Map.

https://leafletjs.com/examples/quick-start/

Comment: @Kyle Great, you can mark my question as answered by hitting the checkmark to the left of my answer.  Though this could be an opportunity for someone to write up a proper tutorial.